# Laravel Homestead & Craft: Craft can’t connect to the database with the credentials in craft/config/db.php

Tags: database, config

I'm following [these instructions](https://medium.com/@mattcollins_6/setting-up-a-local-dev-environment-for-craft-cms-using-laravel-homestead-2724be3954a5#.bsm07bevu) to Setting up a local dev environment for Craft CMS with Laravel Homestead.
When I go to `http://my-craft-site.dev/admin`, I get:

> Craft can’t connect to the database with the credentials in
>   craft/config/db.php.

Not having much luck with Google/Stack searches on the error message. I can connect to the Homestead DB via Sequel Pro using the credentials in db.php so I’m a bit confused by the error message.
DB Credentials:

```
u: homestead
p: secret
```

Comment: Let's see what your `db.php` file looks like.  Check the name of the db in `Homestead.Yaml` as well

Comment: db.php and homestead.yaml contents: https://gist.github.com/komplexb/f1c7f461752e1d91834e

Comment: Assuming `devMode` is on, you can check the console to see the values that Craft is getting from the config. That'll be your first clue. If Craft is getting the right values, and the db isn't responding, it'd be a host issue. If Craft is trying to log in with blank values, it's a config setup issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, reinstall, or in this case do it over again from the top. That fixed it.

Comment: Even after destroying the box and reinstalling I still get the same error.